# How can I inspect data in a Cassini Session?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, cassini

Is there an easy way to inspect the data stored in my Cassini session? I know I can use watch entries, but I wanted to know if there was a better tool.

For example, if I want to see all Keys currently stored in Session, I have to dig down like this: 
[image: Session in Watch]

Then, each time a new value is added, the _entriesTable property collapses and I have to expand it again to see the new values.

Furthermore, if I want to see what is actually stored in session for those values, I have to copy each key and add a new watch for it, `Session["72ddf034-71e6-4a28-9aa1-f8d83245a6fe"]`. If I drill all the way down in the entries table, it shows me the Key and the type of the Value, but I can't drill down into properties of the value here:
[image: Session Key Value]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put break points or use the Immediate Window in Visual Studio to output the contents of `Session`. Cassini makes no difference here.

Comment: I know i can do that. However, lets say I want to see all of the current keys in `Session`, I have to add Session to Watch, dig down into `Keys>Non-Public Members>_coll>Non-Public Members>_entriesTable`. I was hoping for a much easier solution.

Comment: You could just add `Keys>Non-Public Members>_coll>Non-Public Members>_entriesTable` into the watch instead.

Comment: How, exactly, do you suggest I do that? `Session.Keys.Non-Public Members`?

Comment: @scottm Use on plain Session, navigate to what you want, right click it, "Add Watch"

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions would be to use a persistent session provider (like the one which saves the session to your database) and then inspect the stored data with any tools you wish.